# migrating to 4.2 and getting error in has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I have:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :mobile_menus, class_name: "Menu", ~> { where is_instore_enabled: true }
```

but I get the error:

> location.rb:52: syntax error, unexpected '>' (SyntaxError)

for that operator to the where. What am I doing wrong? Is it the class_name?

Comment: You have a syntax error. Change `~>` to `->`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wanted to use `stabby lambda` (`->`) I think.
Not `~>`.

Comment: yeah, I think something like `has_many :mobile_menus, -> { where("is_instore_enabled is 't'")}, class_name: "Menu"`